# How to rotate the canvas incrementally

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, canvas

I have a basic right, left up and down rotating canvas like this;

https://angular-yftnax.stackblitz.io

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yftnax?file=src/main.ts **--for edit**

I want to rotate my canvas (defaults to 0 when the arrow is on top. Between 180 and -180 angles) like in the picture.

[image: angle tool]

**note:The language I wrote is angular, but you can do it with languages ​​such as javascript, I will convert**

Comment: Why do you use `querySelector` in angular?

Comment: I want to rotate it in degrees, for example, I need to be able to rotate the incoming image to the left at an angle of -30 degrees. @vr.

Comment: because this is just an example I made for you to see. @Konrad

Comment: `ctx.rotate(-30 * Math.PI / 180);`

Comment: ok, this isn't exactly working for me, but this gave me an idea of ​​what I want to do. thanks @Konrad